# NotFoundHttpException while using api_token based authentication in laravel 5.2

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-5

I am doing project in laravel 5.2. For authentication, I am using API Token Authentication from Laravel 5.2. I have referred https://gistlog.co/JacobBennett/090369fbab0b31130b51 and my code looks like,

**Routes.php**

```
Route::post('login/','UserController@login');
 Route::group(['prefix' => 'api/v1', 'middleware' => 'auth:api'], function () {
    Route::get('/', function () {
        return "Hi";
    });
});
```

and in **UserController.php** I did simple login as follows,

```
    public function login(Request $request){
        $email = $request->input('email');
        $user = DB::table('users')->where('email',$email)->first();
        return $user->api_token;
    }
```

I am using postman and first I did login and it returns me the correct api_token from table but when I try to access urls within middleware then it throws an error page as,

```
Sorry, the page you are looking for could not be found.

1/1
NotFoundHttpException in RouteCollection.php line 161:
```

I tried,
localhost:8888/ as well as

localhost:8888/api_token=6CnUsIKlmwHXYQNFAuhUTDweUe707gJU2nM2j1Kwjn80nFgmaJHGXuAdN3BX

But still it shows same error page.

Answer (score 0):

Try to change your route / for this code in your Routes.php:

```
Route::post('login/','UserController@login');
Route::group(['prefix' => 'api/v1', 'middleware' => 'auth:api'], function () {
    Route::get('/', array('as'=>'api_login', 'uses' => 'UserController@api_login'));
});
```

And in your UserController.php add:

```
public function api_login(){
    return "Hi";
}
```

I use the Auth class, not an api and if i put the code in Routes.php it didn't work, but if I put the same code inside a Controller and in my Routes.php add the 'uses', it works.

I hope that it works for you too.

Good Luck!

Comment: thanks for your reply. Can you tell me, what should be my route? I am using postman

Comment: The Route may be the same

Comment: I got solution, my route should be as, localhost:8888/api/v1?api_token=6CnUsIKlmwHXYQNFAuhUTDweUe707gJU2nM2j1Kwjn80nFgmaJHGXuAdN3BX

Comment: Perfect, happy to have helped if you found your solution. Regards!

Answer (score 0):

If it helps anyone that googles this issue, I had the same problem and after hours of playing about with it realised it was because I had no api_tokens in my database, once I added it was fine, just weird behaviour that it gives 404 when api_token is not valid.